# Converting binary to varchar in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, binary, varchar

My table consists of a field that is binary_double. However I want to convert it to varchar.

The column currently has sample values stored as binary_double. It looks like this:

69623829

I want the result to be returned in the same format when I convert it to varchar. So expected output is like this:

69623829

I have tried this:

```
select
  convert(varchar(20),r.col_14,1)
from sample_table r
```

The error message is:

> ORA-00936: missing expression

p.s : I am just starting off in PL/SQL

Comment: Try cast rather than convert select cast(r.col_14 as varchar(20)) from sample_table r

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `TO_CHAR` function. See [TO_CHAR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions181.htm).
As in

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(col14,'99999999') FROM sample_table
```

Please see linked documentation for the desired format according to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cast` function:

```
CAST ( { expr | ( subquery ) | MULTISET ( subquery ) } AS type_name )
```

so:

```
select CAST(col_14 as varchar2(20)) from sample_tabe
```

[Oracle live compiler - CAST as varchar2](https://rextester.com/ALTUQ9723)

For more, check this link:

[CAST function](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Database/Oracle_Conversion_Functions/00__Oracle_CAST.htm)

Comment: Using cast function, returns values like 9.537E+007. How do I ensure that the results return values in this format - 95378648 (for e.g)?

Comment: Edit your question please, add some values concretely from your col_14 - and add an expected output.

Comment: I've modifies the question now with expected output.

Comment: Try this: select CAST(to_number(CAST(r.col_14 as binary_double)) as varchar2 (20)) from table r